# Video playback is cut - GPU RX 560

Tags: windows-7, windows, gpu, amd-graphics-card, amd-ryzen

I built a PC with this configuration:

- ASRock B450M Pro4
- Ryzen 5 2600
- RX 560 OC 2 GB
- Windows 7

When I play video at 720p / 1080p / 4K / 8K, it cuts so terribly.
When I play the VLC video on a PC, it is also choppy.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Do these First and Then Try again to see if that Resolved your issue.

- Verify that the Video cable is plugged into your Graphics card.
- Verify that you have the latest drivers for your Graphics Card.

These Might or Might not work for you, They have worked for me in the past.

- Change you power plan settings to High performance in Control Panel.
- Go into AMD Radeon setting and Reset to Factory Defaults.
- Make Sure Your Bios does not have enable any ECO or Power Saving settings Enabled.

Let Me know when performance changes and what setting you changed.

If this was an issue from day one, You might have a bad card.

And if all else fails, try putting it in a different PC, if it still gives you issues,  Then its probably a bad card. Most Vendors will take the card back if it is faulty.

Comment: No, it did not help.

Comment: Is it also an issue with Windows Media Player?

Comment: Videos are choppy on both YouTube (in any resolution) and PC on VLC. I'm afraid it will be the same everywhere.

Comment: Is your video cable plugged into the motherboard or graphics card? And do you have the latest drivers for your graphics card?